Ошибка при установке граб в арч линукс при установке арч линукса
как исправить ошибку will not with blocklists. при установке арч линукс на виртуальную машину виртуал бокс ошибка возникает после написания команды sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Если что у меня используется BIOS а не UIFE ТАК КАК я забыл поставить галочку во время создания виртуальной машины разделы диска
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sda4

Что такое вообще граб и обязатенли он вообще

Целиком ошибку покажите. "Что такое вообще граб" Это проще загуглить.
